# How do I get the source artifact from CodePipeline on CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I'm using the official AWS documentation to create a pipeline using CDK: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/cdk_pipeline.html#cdk_pipeline_define (with a slight variation to the docs, where I used a CodeStar connection, as the code comments recommend)

This automatically creates a self-mutating pipeline, with three stages -- Source, Synth, and UpdatePipeline. That's great.

I would like to add a new stage with a CodeBuild action. I'd like the CodeBuild action to be based on the buildspec.yml file in the source directory.

On the console, I can easily do this by clicking "Add new stage", "Add action", and selecting the input artifact from the dropdown menu.

However, on CDK, with this recommended setup there's no easy way to get access to the input artifacts.

I managed to do it by forcing `buildPipeline()` and doing this:

```js
import * as cdk from "@aws-cdk/core";
import {
  CodePipeline,
  ShellStep,
  CodePipelineSource,
} from "@aws-cdk/pipelines";
import * as codebuild from "@aws-cdk/aws-codebuild";
import * as codepipelineActions from "@aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline-actions";


export class PipelineStack extends cdk.Stack {
  public readonly source: cdk.CfnOutput

  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const source = CodePipelineSource.connection("someuser/somerepo", "master", {
      connectionArn: "arn:aws:codestar-connections:us-east-1:REDACTED:connection/REDACTED"
    });

    const synthShellStep = new ShellStep("Synth", {
      input: source,
      commands: [
          "cd infrastructure",
          "npm run ci",
          "npm run build",
          "npx cdk synth"
      ],
      "primaryOutputDirectory": "infrastructure/cdk.out"
    });

    const pipeline = new CodePipeline(this, "Pipeline", {
      pipelineName: "FancyPipeline",
      synth: synthShellStep
    });

    // Need to build the pipeline to access the
    // source artifact
    pipeline.buildPipeline();

    const sourceStage = pipeline.pipeline.stage("Source");
    if (sourceStage) {
      const sourceOutputs = sourceStage.actions[0].actionProperties.outputs;
      if (sourceOutputs && sourceOutputs.length > 0) {
        const sourceArtifact = sourceOutputs[0];


        const codeBuildProject = new codebuild.PipelineProject(this, 'DockerBuildProject', {
          environment: {
            privileged: true
          }
        });

        const buildAction = new codepipelineActions.CodeBuildAction({
          actionName: 'DockerBuild',
          project: codeBuildProject,
          input: sourceArtifact,
          environmentVariables: {
            AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: {
              value: this.region
            },
            AWS_ACCOUNT_ID: {
              value: this.account
            },
            IMAGE_REPO_NAME: {
              value: "somereponame"
            },
            IMAGE_TAG: {
              value: "latest"
            }
          }
        });

        pipeline.pipeline.addStage({
          stageName: "DockerBuildStage",
          actions: [buildAction],
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But this feels overall pretty awkward, and I can't call `addStage()` on the `CodePipeline` construct anymore. Surely there's a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Any help/advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: why can't you call addStage anymore? 

Take a look here at the offical documentation and see if you can help find what you need:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.pipelines/README.html

As an aside, the Pipelines library (that allows use of the self mutating pipeline) is still experimental and in development, so isn't 100% stable and may change drastically in a future update. Keep that in mind when updating CDK versions.

Comment: The `CodePipeline` construct does not allow calling `addStage` after `buildPipeline` has been called. I can, however, call `addStage` on the `Pipeline` construct, accessible via the `pipeline` property of the `CodePipeline` construct. It's weird there are several different APIs for the same thing. The link does not answer the question of accessing the source artifact, it's merely a copy of the same documentation I've been reading, only in Python.

Comment: oops sorry didnt realize i was on the python page - do so out of habit.  -- you can try defining your source artificts yourself (using `aws_codepipeline.Artifact()` ) before you use buildPipeline and then use those in the various stages. Its better practice to do this anyways as then you have more control over the artifact and its settings than letting cdk do the design.

Answer (score 0):

The `codepipelineActions.CodeBuildAction` method accepts a parameter titled `outputs` which is for the list of output Artifacts for this action. TypeScript source [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline.ActionProperties.html). I think it's easier to follow in the python version of the docs though (link [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_codepipeline_actions/CodeBuildAction.html)).